# Как правильно описывать enum в sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Создал свое поле ENUM [как в документации](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) по значениям из строк в БД ('one / 1', 'two / 2')

```
import enum
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy import  Column, String, Boolean, BigInteger, Enum

class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    one = 'one / 1'
    two = 'two / 2'

class Test(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(BigInteger, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    value = Column(Enum(MyEnum))
```

Но при выборе всех данных из таблицы данных

```
sql = select(Test).where(Test.name == 'имя_со_всеми_enum')
engine = create_engine('mysql://MYroot:MYpass@127.0.0.1:3307/My_bd', echo=True)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    print(pd.read_sql(sql, conn))
```

выдает ошибку:

```
LookupError: 'one / 1' is not among the defined enum values. Enum name: enumuseragent. Possible values: one , two
```

Есть предположение, что неправильно описал класс **MyEnum**, если так, то в чем просчитался?

Comment: ну вы же делаете НЕ так, как в документации.

Comment: В документации же написано, что значения енумов не используются, используются только имена. Хотите использовать значения - для этого есть параметр `Enum.params.values_callable`, читайте в той же документации.

Answer (score 0):

Во-общем, если кто столкнется вот решение:

```
class Test(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(BigInteger, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    value = Column(Enum(MyEnum).values_callable)
```